# When and when not to use Compression in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, compression, backend, web-development-server

In NodeJs, we have something called compression which can be used to compress the sending data to client.
I want to know when we should use Compression and when we should not use.
What are the **consequences** of using Compression.
Is it a good practice to use compression.

Comment: Compression costs compute time and saves bandwidth.  That's the trade-off.  Unless you have very large transmissions, it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: So if we are sending huge bulk of data then we should go for compression otherwise it's okay to not be use.

Comment: Compression was way more useful when people had low-bandwidth dial-up connections.  Today, it's hard to see, but yes, what you said is the general rule I'd use.

Answer (score 0):

Compression costs compute time and saves bandwidth. In today's time you can skip if you have general REST HTTP API

Also this package is heavier to import, see below screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5ayp.png

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).